# Tuple unpacking while indexing

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

This works:

```
x = ['foo', 'bar']
y = [*x]
print(y)  # prints ['foo', 'bar']
```

but this doesn't:

```
x = ['foo', 'bar']
y[*x]  # raises SyntaxError (not NameError!)
```

How can I unpack tuples while indexing?

Here are two examples where I'd like to use this approach, but I'm more interested in understanding why `*`-unpacking seems not to be supported in indexing in general.

```py
import numpy as np

def lookup(a: np.ndarray, coordinates: tuple) -> float:
    return a[*coordinates]

a1 = np.zeros((2, 2))
print(lookup(a1, (0, 1))  # Should print 0

a2 = np.zeros(2, 2, 2))
print(lookup(a2, (0, 0, 1))  # Should print 0
```

or

```py
from typing import Tuple

NUM_DIMENSIONS = 2  # Might change at a later point in time

# Should be equivalent to Tuple[float ,float]
Result = Tuple[*([float] * NUM_DIMENSIONS)]

def get() -> Result:
    ...
```

Comment: In your second snippet `y` has not been introduced as a variable, so `y[*x]` means nothing hence the syntax error.

Comment: How do you expect indexing to work with `['foo', 'bar']` here? Indexing requires an individual integer, not a list of strings

Comment: Can you show an example with desired outputs for the inputs?

Comment: @quamrana: No, a missing variable declaration raises a `NameError`, not a `SyntaxError`. Try `not_declared[0]`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: For lists that may be true. But NumPy arrays, Pandas DataFrames and `typing` Generics have a much more complicated indexing interface and do support things like `foo[a, b, c]`. See my examples.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I've updated my examples with the expected behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's indexing already has built-in support for tuples in general (not just for NumPy), so there is no need for unpacking here.

In general, `foo[x]` is [syntactic sugar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names) for `type(foo).__getitem__(foo, x)`. Let's see how that works in detail:

```py
class Foo: 
    def __getitem__(self, key): 
        print(repr(key)) 

foo = Foo()
```

If we index into `foo` with a single value then it is passed to `__getitem__` unchanged, no matter whether it is a scalar, a list, or a tuple:

```
foo[0]       # prints 0
foo[(0, 1)]  # prints (0, 1)
foo[[0, 1]]  # prints [0, 1]
```

The interesting case is what happens when we supply multiple values directly while indexing (without wrapping them in a tuple or list):

```
foo[0, 1]  # prints (0, 1)
```

So multiple values are automatically wrapped in a tuple! `foo` cannot distinguish between `foo[0, 1]` and `foo[(0, 1)]`. This is because in the [Python grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html), the index is an expression (or a slice, but that doesn't apply here) -- and in an expression, a `,` forms a tuple:

```py
x = 1, 2
print(repr(x))  # prints (1, 2)
```

Hence, argument parsing in indexing works differently then for function calls (where commas separate arguments instead of forming tuples).

So, overall, there is no need for iterator unpacking in indexing. Simply convert your iterator to a tuple use it as the index.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your example:

```py
import numpy as np

def lookup(a: np.ndarray, coordinates: tuple) -> float:
    return a[*coordinates]

a1 = np.zeros((2, 2))
print(lookup(a1, (0, 1))

a2 = np.zeros(2, 2, 2))
print(lookup(a2, (0, 0, 1))
```

NumPy already accepts indexing like `a[coordinates]` where `coordinates` is a tuple, without need for the star operator:

```py
>>> a = np.arange(8).reshape(2, 2, 2)
>>> a[(1, 1, 0)]
6
```

And if you index with lists, you get a different kind of useful behaviour:

```py
>> a[[1, 1, 0], [0]]
array([[4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [0, 1]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. As I've written I'm less concerned with getting the examples working and more with understanding why my approach does not work (although I would be interested in a workaround for my `typing` example).

Answer (score -1):

```
x = ['foo', 'bar']
y[*x]  # raises SyntaxError (not NameError!)
```

This is raising syntax error because the * and x are being taken as two separate things, rather than one.
For eg : if I do the following

```
type(*x)
```

this returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: type() takes 1 or 3 arguments
```

which means that *x is not treated as a single entity but two separate.

Also,

```
>>> x = ['foo', 'bar']
>>> print(*x)
foo bar
>>> print(x)
['foo', 'bar']
>>> y[*x]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    y[*x]
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> y[foo bar]  #this is y[*x]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    y[foo bar]
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Your error for `type(*x)` is because `x` has the wrong number of elements. Iterator unpacking in function arguments works fine for `type`: `type(*[1])` returns `int`. The first part of your second example is what I'm asking about (and you offer no explanation here), and there's a missing comma in the second part of your second example.

Comment: type(*['foo','bar']) or type(*[1,2]) would give you the error I specified. Also, there is no missing comma, but the *x itself prints foo bar rather than ['foo', 'bar'] unless I misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes, `type(*['foo', 'bar'])` would also give the same error, but I don't see what that has to do with the tuple unpacking syntax not being supported in indexing operations. As I said, unpacking is well-supported in function calls. Regarding the missing comma: I don't see how `y[foo bar]` is supposed to be valid Python syntax and what it has to do with unpacking -- your comment `this is y[*x]` doesn't make much sense, since `y[*x]` is not defined (that's what my question is all about) and if it was defined it would surely not expand to something that is syntactically invalid like `y[foo bar]`.

Comment: y = [*x],  I referred from your question and y[*x] is giving you the syntax error(as per question), so my whole point of explanation was y[*x] will give you syntax error and you got that because accessing y[*x] is accessing y[foo bar] which is syntactical incorrect as expected.

Comment: I don't think that "`y[*x]` is accessing `y[foo bar]`" makes any sense. What's "accessing" supposed t o mean? As you can see from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001631/857390) this is a question of how exactly `y[x]` desugars into `type(y).__getitem__(y, x)`  and on what kind of grammatical entity is expected between `[` and `]` (e.g. an expression vs. a parameter list).