# Unpack list into numpy.r_

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.9

I want to use `np.r_` on list of ranges.

I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
indexes = [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
print(np.r_[*indexes])
```

I expected `[1 2 3 5 6 7]` as output, but the code raises `SyntaxError`.

Why?

Comment: I learned from experience that you can't really unpack iterable for indexing with `[]`. Maybe `np.concatenate(indexes)`?

Comment: `r_` is actually using indexing syntax here, [] not function ().  Why do you need to use `r_`?

Comment: @hpaulj Ok, now I understand that I don't need `r_` here.

But still: why unpacking does not work with indexing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.r_[*indexes]` does not work, because unpacking does not work with indexing.

#### Why unpacking does not work with indexing?

Because `x[i]` is syntactic sugar for `type(x).__getitem__(x, i)` and `__getitem__` takes only one argument(except `self`). [more about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001631/12037382)

#### How to unpack itarable into index?

```py
np.r_[(*indexes,)]
# or
np.r_[tuple(indexes)]
```