# Mixing numpy fancy indexing with ellipsis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, ellipsis

How can I combine fancy indexing with `...` in numpy?

Consider some test data:

```
# Some test data of high dimensionality 
shape = (3,5,2,8)
data = np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)
```

Maybe I have a tuple of indices. I cannot unpack these values during indexing:

```
# Arbitrary indices
indices = (0, 4)
# Try unpacking
data[*indices]
# >>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Not to worry, I get the same result if I pass the indices individually or as a tuple — nice!

```
np.all(data[indices[0], indices[1]] == data[indices])
# >>> True
```

So unpacking is not needed, right? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65001631/6238395) to a related question seems to imply so.

> Python's indexing already has built-in support for tuples in general [...] there is no need for iterator unpacking in indexing. Simply convert your iterator to a tuple

At first glance, it even seems to work with fancy indexing:

```
# New arbitrary indices
new_indices = (np.array([0,1]), np.array([4,4]))
np.all(data[new_indices] == data[new_indices[0], new_indices[1]])
# >>> True
```

But if I try to use `ellipsis` it breaks down. For example if I want to do fancy indexing on trailing axes:

```
# Passing unpacked values produces the desired result
data[..., new_indices[0], new_indices[1]] # shape=(3,5,2)
# Passing as a tuple does NOT produce the desired result
data[..., new_indices] # shape=(3,5,2,2,2)
```

Of course if my data is of variable dimensionality, I cannot write `..., new_indices[0], new_indices[1]`. So it seems that in this case unpacking is in fact needed.

Okay, well maybe I can just do this:

```
data.T[indices[::-1]].T.shape # shape=(3,5,2)
```

It feels a bit hacky, but it works. Except if we want to have fancy indexing at both leading and trailing axes with `...` in between, it seems we are truly out of luck:

```
# Some test data of even higher dimensionality 
data_shape = (3,5,2,8,12,25)
data = np.arange(np.prod(data_shape)).reshape(data_shape)

index_A = (np.array([0,0,1]), np.array([0,2,1]))
index_B = (np.array([0,0,0]), np.array([1,1,1]))

# Desired result, shape=(3,2)
data[index_A[0], index_A[1], ..., index_B[0], index_B[1]]
# Without unpacking, shape=(2,3,5,2,8)
data[index_A, ..., index_B]
```

Maybe this is an edge case, but it seems there should be a way to do it. How?

P.S. Why should iterable unpacking raise a SyntaxError in this situation, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tuple` join does the trick:

```
In [142]: data[(...,)+indices]
Out[142]: 
array([[  4,  20,  36,  52,  68],
       [ 84, 100, 116, 132, 148],
       [164, 180, 196, 212, 228]])
In [143]: data[...,0,4]
Out[143]: 
array([[  4,  20,  36,  52,  68],
       [ 84, 100, 116, 132, 148],
       [164, 180, 196, 212, 228]])

In [144]: (...,)+indices
Out[144]: (Ellipsis, 0, 4)
```

unpacking inside a tuple also works:

```
data[(...,*indices)]
```